# Emacs 23 for mixed PHP and HTML

Tags: emacs, nxhtml

I'm trying to use emacs23.1.1 with nXhtml for web development, writing mixed PHP and HTML. Whenever I do, though, I seem to encounter some strange emacs behaviour.

As one example, I write the following code:

```
    <?php
        echo "a";
    ?>
```

As I write the line `echo "a";`, I go to the previous line and press C-j and start typing - then, as I press ; (, does the same):

```
    <?php
echo "a";
    ?>
```

Pressing `<TAB>` sends the echo back to

```
    <?php
        echo "a";
    ?>
```

Very, very annoying... Any ideas?

This is my minified init.el:

```
(load "~/.emacs.d/lib/nxhtml/autostart.el")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Emacs provides a way around this so far unsolved issue: org-babel allows to line up code from different languages.
You may use php-mode than for the php-part. An exporter transfers all into one html finally.

At emacs-orgmode@gnu.org you should get further help.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion - I'll see if I can figure it out. Seems like a fairly advanced mode.